# how to merge rows in datatable which had same value (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, datarow, merge-replication

I have one datatable tempDT with value :

```
Serial_No                      testong
---------------------------------------
DTSHCSN001205035919201         [ OUT ] <br/> Partner : 90000032 <br/> Date : 16 Feb 2012
DTSHCSN001205035919201         [ IN ] <br/> Partner : 90000032 <br/> Date : 16 Feb 2012
DTSHCSN001205035919201         [ OUT ] <br/> Partner : 80000869 <br/> Date : 31 Mar 2012
DTSHCSN001205035919201         [ IN ] <br/> Partner : 80000869 <br/> Date : 31 Mar 2012
```

The problem is I want merge duplicate serial_no into one row which the value of testong adding to new column.

I have tried many ways, but I can't find the solution.

Here is my code behind :

```
    Dim tempDt = GetItemDataTable()
    Dim dtData As New DataTable

    dtData.Columns.Add("Serial_No")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim row As DataRow

    For Each row In tempDt.Rows
        i += 1
        Dim dr As DataRow = dtData.NewRow
        dr("Serial_No") = row(0)
        If dr("Serial_No") = row(0) Then
            Dim colBaru As GridViewDataTextColumn = New GridViewDataTextColumn()
            colBaru.Caption = i
            colBaru.FieldName = i
            colBaru.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
            colBaru.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
            colBaru.Width = 150

            colBaru.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Integer
            colBaru.VisibleIndex = grid.VisibleColumns.Count
            colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "d1"
            colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.EncodeHtml = True
            grid.Columns.Add(colBaru)
            dtData.Columns.Add(i)
            dr(i) = row(3)
            dtData.Rows.Add(dr)

        Else
            dr("Serial_No") = row(0)
            dtData.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
```

When I debug the result is :
[image: wrong result]

But I wanted the result is like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my code, so it would look at the columns rather using variable i

```
Dim tempDt = GetItemDataTable()
Dim dtData As New DataTable

'initial the first and second columns
dtData.Columns.Add("Serial_No")
dtData.Columns.Add("1")

Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim row As DataRow

For Each row In tempDt.Rows
    Dim dr As DataRow
    i += 1
    'check if the serial no exists in the new Data Table
    If dtData.Select("Serial_No='" & row(0) & "'").Length > 0 Then



        'If found, then get the existing row
        dr = dtData.Select("Serial_No='" & row(0) & "'")(0)

        'Create new GridViewDataTextColumn
        Dim colBaru As GridViewDataTextColumn = New GridViewDataTextColumn()
        colBaru.Caption = i
        colBaru.FieldName = i
        colBaru.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        colBaru.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center


        colBaru.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Integer
        colBaru.VisibleIndex = grid.VisibleColumns.Count
        colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "d1"
        colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.EncodeHtml = False
        grid.Columns.Add(colBaru)

        'I assume you are adding the Number as the columns name
        'Only need to create if the Column doesn't exist
        If dtData.Columns.count - 1 < i Then
            dtData.Columns.Add(i.ToString) 
        End If

        'Use variable i here
        dr(i) = row(3)

        'Comment this out as you don't need to
        'dtData.Rows.Add(dr)
    Else

        'reset value of i
        i = 1

        'If not found, then create a new row  
        dr = dtData.NewRow
        ' i put this to add the serial_no value to datatable
        dr("Serial_No") = row(0)

        'for adding first value i with same row as serial_no
        Dim colBaru As GridViewDataTextColumn = New GridViewDataTextColumn()
        colBaru.Caption = i
        colBaru.FieldName = i
        colBaru.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        colBaru.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center


        colBaru.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Integer
        colBaru.VisibleIndex = grid.VisibleColumns.Count
        colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "d1"
        colBaru.PropertiesTextEdit.EncodeHtml = False
        grid.Columns.Add(colBaru)

        'dtData.Columns.Add("1")

        'Would be better to use back variable i if you have reset it
        dr(i) = row(3)


        dtData.Rows.Add(dr)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks nick for your response but its still not giving the correct solution but its close by. You forget something, i put dr(Serial_No) = row(0) if else condition after dr= dtData.NewRow for adding Serial_No .And the problem now is the value of row(3) in the first loop not add to datatable. so after row(0) added they read the second value of row(3). i had try put dr(i) = row(3) in else condition. but its not working.

Comment: just wonder if you put `dr(Serial_No) = row(0)` before the if else condition, should your condition always been true? So it won't create a new row, will it? Also because i is declared in side if, so you only need to put `dtData.Columns.Add(1)` then `dr(0) = row(3)`

Comment: yap that is right but if u don't put dr(serial) = row(0) in else condition, it will not insert any value. i had modified your answer. and its working correctly. anyways thanks a lot... today is my deadline for this modul. hehe you are my savior. :P

Comment: sorry interrupting you. but i still had incorrect result. parameter i+=1 always looping include when i had new rows. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AC7fp.jpg

Comment: its still giving an. for every column i will get error indexoutofrange "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 1."